# st7789 TFT Driver parallel read

Tags: embedded

I want to read the ID of my St7789 driver through the parallel interface.
I'm using a 16 bit parallel interface.(DB1-DB16)
I am running the Read ID3 command.
I'm writing the DCh hexadecimal code to the controller.
Then I go to read.
The value to read is 0x52.
When reading, I send D / CX WRX and RDX signals.
But I never read the correct values ​​from the parallel pins.

The code looks like this.

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;

  set_rs; / * RS high * /

  set_nw; / * Wr high * /

  clr_nrd; / * Rd low * /

  // DB1-DB8 <-> PC1-PC8 and DB10-DB12 <-> PC10-PC12
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_1 | GPIO_Pin_2 | GPIO_Pin_3 | 
  GPIO_Pin_4 | GPIO_Pin_5 | GPIO_Pin_6 | GPIO_Pin_7 | GPIO_Pin_8 | 
  GPIO_Pin_10 | GPIO_Pin_11 | gpıo_pin_12;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed ​​ = GPIO_Speed_50 MHz;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_IN;
  GPIO_Init (GPIOC, & GPIO_InitStructure);

  // DB13 PD2
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_2;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed ​​ = GPIO_Speed_50 MHz;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_IN;
  GPIO_Init (GPIOD, & GPIO_InitStructure);

  // DB14 <-> PB9, DB15 <-> PB10, DB16 <-> PB1, DB17 <-> PB2
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_1 | GPIO_Pin_2 | GPIO_Pin_9 | 
  GPIO_pin_10;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed ​​ = GPIO_Speed_50 MHz;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_IN;
  GPIO_Init (GPIOB, & GPIO_InitStructure);

  // We read twice to be sure.
  PORTREAD();//16 bit Parallel read.
  PORTREAD();

  // DB1-DB8 <-> PC1-PC8 and DB10-DB12 <-> PC10-PC12
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_1 | GPIO_Pin_2 | GPIO_Pin_3 | 
  GPIO_Pin_4 | GPIO_Pin_5 | GPIO_Pin_6 | GPIO_Pin_7 | GPIO_Pin_8 | 
  GPIO_Pin_10 
  | GPIO_Pin_11 | gpıo_pin_12;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed ​​ = GPIO_Speed_50 MHz;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_OUT;
  GPIO_Init (GPIOC, & GPIO_InitStructure);

  // DB13 PD2
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_2;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed ​​ = GPIO_Speed_50 MHz;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_OUT;
  GPIO_Init (GPIOD, & GPIO_InitStructure);

  // DB14 <-> PB9, DB15 <-> PB10, DB16 <-> PB1, DB17 <-> PB2
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_1 | GPIO_Pin_2 | GPIO_Pin_9 | 
  GPIO_pin_10;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed ​​ = GPIO_Speed_50 MHz;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_OUT;
  GPIO_Init (GPIOB, & GPIO_InitStructure);


  set_nrd; / * Rd high * /
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

First, the D / CX WRX RDX signals are sent. Next parallel pins are routed from the output to the input for reading.
We read it later.
Am I sending the RD signals wrong ?(High and low in wrong sequence)
How should the D / CX WRX RDX signal sequence be ?

Comment: OK
I have found the error now.
ID reading is done with 3 consecutive readings.
If you set the pins output  between 3 readings, the read value is a nonsense value.
We need to set the ports output after the most reading is finished.we must cancel the locations where the pins are set output..